# Choosing one element from each partition that minimize the difference between max and min

Tags: algorithms

Given an unsorted array $A$ that contains $n$ elements of numbers. Also $A$ partitioned to $k$ lists $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots,A_k$, each contains at most nearly $\frac{n}{k}$ elements. We choose exactly one elements from each $A_i$ so that difference between maximum and minimum element minimized. Can this be done in $O(n\log k)$ time?

I think this can't be done in better than $\Omega (n\log n)$ because assume already we know the value of our optimal solution, name it $t$. Also assume $A$ not partitioned and our goal is find two elements $a$ and $b$ from $A$ such $|a-b|=t$. We know that the lower bound of a such problem is $\Omega (n\log n)$. Could we say my argument is true or not?

Comment: Your argument is in right direction, however, it is not completely formal. There are $k$ partitions; and you have used the same notation in $|a-b| = k$. I am assuming, you are considering $k = 1$ partitions for proving your lower bound argument.

Also, this lower bound is only for comparison based model.